# Access Denied installing updates remotely with Powershell

Tags: powershell, updates, wsus

Im trying to install in a remote server, updates approved in our Wsus:

```
$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName server1
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    (Import-module -name "S:\temp\PSWindowsUpdate" -Verbose),
    (Get-WindowsUpdate | Format-Table -Verbose)
    Enable-WURemoting
    (Install-module pswindowsupdate -force -Accept -SkipPublisherCheck -AllowClobber),
    (Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -AutoReboot -Verbose)}
```

But i get this access denied error:

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsUpdate], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,PSWindowsUpdate.GetWindowsUpdate
+ PSComputerName        : server1

I am administrator of the remote server.

Its not possible launch de updates installation on remote servers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install updates on a computer from a remote session. [here's a list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/using-wua-from-a-remote-computer?redirectedfrom=MSDN) what you can and can't do using WUA from a remote computer.

Since you use `PSWindowsUpdate` you can use `Invoke-WUJob` which creates and runs a scheduled task on the remote computer, working around the WUA limitation. e.g:

```
invoke-WUJob -ComputerName MyComputer -Script { Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -SendReport -IgnoreReboot } -Confirm:$false -verbose -RunNow
```

There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078958/powershell-remote-microsoft-update-session-access-denied-0x80070005/60046097) to work around this, however i find this the easiest.

Comment: To use that i can do it with GPO... many thank Simons

Comment: @RAN55 no problem. Show your appreciation by clicking the checkmark Icon to mark this question as solved please, thanks :)

Comment: I still have no reputation :(

Comment: @RAN55 you should be able to mark it as solved without rep. you just can't upvote